# Specify current month in file path preventing having to change macro each month

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run the following macro on a file in the current month's folder.  I have a macro working which locates the current month's folder on a shared drive location and successfully Calls this macro.  However, the below macro specifies March but I'm looking for a way to specify "current month" so I don't have to change the macro every month.
(This macro just converts .csv to .xlsx but is only for test purposes now.)

```
Sub Reject_Review()



ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;G:\Rejects\2017\March\Test_3.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "Test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Month(Now).  Watch the format, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the VBA `Format` keyword which

> Returns a Variant (String) containing an expression formatted
>   according to instructions contained in a format expression..
>
> *Format(expression[, format[, firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]]])*
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Don't forget your year will need updating as well.

```
"TEXT;G:\Rejects\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\Test_3.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

This function works for me in VBA:

```
Function GetMonth() As String

    GetMonth = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "mmmm")
End Function
```